# Method call itself without method name?

Tags: python

```
class C:
  def M:
    self.M()
```

Can Instead of `self.M`, like `self.__FUNC__`? so when the function name change will not change the code inside the function

Comment: No, it cannot, because the code in a function object has no reference to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but you can sort of do it with a decorator that makes sure the attribute is defined before each call to the original function. You'd also need to save and restore the attribute in case multiple methods were similarly decorated and they called one another.

```
import functools

def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        save = getattr(self, '_FUNC_', None)
        self._FUNC_ = func
        retval = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._FUNC_ = save
        if save:  self._FUNC_ = save
        else: delattr(self, '_FUNC_')
        return retval
    return wrapper

class C(object):
    @decorator
    def M(self, i):
        if i > 0:
            print i,
            self._FUNC_(self, i-1)  # explicit 'self' argument required
        else:
            print '- Blast Off!'

C().M(3)  # -> 3 2 1 - Blast Off!
```

Note that`self._FUNC_`isn't a bound method because the decorator is called when the class is constructed. This means a`self`must be explicitly passed to the method as the first argument whenever it's called from within the decorated method.

**Update**

One way to fix that is to not create the wrapper function until the first time the method is actually called (and then save it to reduce future overhead). This will allow it to be called like any other method. I got idea for a solution from the [PythonDecoratorLibrary](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) example titled [*Class method decorator using instance*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Class_method_decorator_using_instance).

```
import functools

def decorator(f):
    """
    Method decorator specific to the instance.

    Uses a special descriptor to delay the definition of the method wrapper.
    """
    class SpecialDescriptor(object):
        def __init__(self, f):
            self.f = f

        def __get__(self, instance, cls):
            if instance is None:  # unbound method request?
                return self.make_unbound(cls)
            return self.make_bound(instance)

        def make_unbound(self, cls):
            @functools.wraps(self.f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                raise TypeError('unbound method {}() must be called with {} '
                                'instance as first argument'.format(
                                                                self.f.__name__,
                                                                cls.__name__))
            return wrapper

        def make_bound(self, instance):
            @functools.wraps(self.f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                save = getattr(instance, '_FUNC_', None)
                instance._FUNC_ = getattr(instance, self.f.__name__)
                retval = self.f(instance, *args, **kwargs)
                if save:  instance._FUNC_ = save  # restore any previous value
                else: delattr(instance, '_FUNC_')
                return retval

            # instance no longer needs special descriptor, since method is now
            # wrapped, so make it call the wrapper directly from now on
            setattr(instance, self.f.__name__, wrapper)
            return wrapper

    return SpecialDescriptor(f)

class C(object):
    @decorator
    def M(self, i):
        if i > 0:
            print i,
            self._FUNC_(i-1)  # No explicit 'self' argument required
        else:
            print '- Blast Off!'

C().M(3)  # -> 3 2 1 - Blast Off!
```

Comment: i think it's not actually OP asking for

Comment: @Zagorulkin: "Can Instead of `self.M`, like `self.__FUNC__`?" seemed relatively clear to me -- I also think @Martijn's interpretation was something similar.